# How to calculate crc32 in psi/si packet

Tags: vb.net, udp

We are working on sending UDP packets to PSI SI. We are developing PSI SI generator.
But we are stuck on CheckSum CRC32 - we are not able to find the check sum. I tried on few code from the internet . It comes up with some checksum but that checksum doesnt match with wireshark check sum .

We have wireshark dump of the PSISI packets working with correct checksum .

Can anyoone help me in calculating the checksum for the PSI SI ?

Regards,
vipul

Answer (score 1):

I am just developing a DVB-S Head station and manipulating the SI-data I ran into the same problem. The solution is to read the ISO/IEC 13818-1 exactly and use the right algorithm.

ISO/IEC 13818-1 describes that the beginning of a section of a PSI-Table is indicated by a **pointer field** in the same Transport Stream packet payload. This means, that there always is a pointer field in front of the section data and this pointer field must not be put in the checksum calculation. The first byte of the pointer field is the length of the field data. In most cases there is no field data and you find a simple zero in front of your section data that starts with the table id of the section. Don´t take this zero into the checksum calculation.

MPEG´s CRC 32 is a cyclic unreflected redundancy check that starts with 0xffffffff and takes the highest bits first. The magic value is 0x04C11DB7 that can be easily derived by the polynom specified in ISO/IEC 13818-1 Annex B with assigning each bit to the polynomial exponent.

Putting all together you have this simple code to calculate the checksum:

```
uint calcCrc32(byte[] sectionData, int sectionDataLength)
{

    uint crc32 = 0xffffffff;
    for (int i = 1 + sectionData[0]; i < sectionDataLength; i++)
    {
        byte b = sectionData[i];
        for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++)
        {
            if ((crc32 >= 0x80000000) != (b >= 0x80))
                crc32 = (crc32 << 1) ^ 0x04C11DB7;
            else
                crc32 = (crc32 << 1);
            b <<= 1;
        }
    }
    return crc32;
}
```